# iText unicode font issue

Tags: java, fonts, alignment, reporting, itext

I have been working with ttf font in java using itext (lowagie) sdk. I would like to explain my problem by example.

I have a table row where I want to show some text ( bengali ttf). The text is supposed to take 2 lines but it is taking 3 lines. The problem is, first line is showing only 5 words and huge white space at the end visually it  appears like it can take 8 words easily.

Please note that if I use English I don't face such problem. I assume that the bengali unicode is causing the problem. If there is any workout regarding the problem then it would be great.

I re-explain my problem by example:

```
Output:

Line1: AAA BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE <BLANK SPACE BLANK SPACE>ENDOFLINE

Line2: CC DD EE PP QQ RR SS EE <BLANK SPACE BLANK SPACE>ENDOFLINE

Line3: CC DD EE PP QQ RR       <BLANK SPACE BLANK SPACE>ENDOFLINE


Expected:

Line1: AAA BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE CC DD EE PP  #ENDOFLINE

Line2: QQ RR SS EE CC DD EE PP QQ RR    #ENDOFLINE
```

Source Module:

```
fontpath="D://Bangla.ttf";
this.banglaFont = BaseFont.createFont(fontpath,BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);



        PdfPTable bTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        bTable.getDefaultCell().setBorder(1);
        bTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
        bTable.addCell(backTableRow1cell(28.5f, 8.8f, CardStr.GOVTNOTE_BNG));




public static PdfPCell backTableRow1cell(float hght, float fontSize, String txt) {
    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell();
    c1.setFixedHeight(hght);
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    ITextUtil.setCellBorder(c1, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    ITextUtil.setCellPadding(c1, 0, 7, 0, 0);
    c1.addElement(TextProcessing.designPar(TextProcessing.getFontStyle(VoterCard.banglaFont, fontSize, Color.BLACK, Font.NORMAL), txt, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 8, 2));
    return c1;
}
public static Paragraph designPar(Font fnt, String txt, int alignment, int leading, int afterspacing) {
    Paragraph phrs = new Paragraph(txt, fnt);
    phrs.setLeading(leading);
    phrs.setAlignment(alignment);
    return phrs;
}

public static Font getFontStyle(BaseFont baseFont, float size, Color clr, int FontStyle) {
    Font fnt = new Font(baseFont, size);
    fnt.setColor(clr);
    fnt.setStyle(FontStyle);

    return fnt;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide self-contained source code and a sample PDF.

Comment: hi @mkl  I have added code snippet and a screen shot, i dont see pdf attachment option here!

Comment: Your getFontStyle() method won't work. The style is already defined by the baseFont object; you can't change it. I think Bengali requires ligatures. Currently this is only supported for Arabic, not for Indic. What is the value of CardStr.GOVTNOTE_BNG? Maybe it contains non-breaking space characters instead of normal spaces. Plenty of other things could be wrong, but nobody will be able to help you without a sample that reproduces the problem. You're using the classes with my name (lowagie). That version is obsolete: http://lowagie.com/itext2 Maybe you're facing a bug that is already fixed.

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt As Bruno explained, your source code is not self contained; furthermore, there is no sample PDF to inspect.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I tried itext-2.1.7 just now, in this case the text spacing problem fixes but some complex letter breaks apart :(

Comment: @mkl , I will have to recode the entire thing if i need to provide it here as I don't see source attachment option! As you can see from image, I am trying to trim the trailing spaces. Could u provide a way to solve that ?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie CardStr.GOVTNOTE_BNG is the same string that i used in openoffice to pdf too! In that case, I got expected result. the seperating space is normal " " . I am little bit confused regarding which version should I use!

Comment: Some complex letter breaks apart = the ligature isn't made, because ligatures aren't supported (not in 2.1.7, not in the latest version).

Comment: Thanks, at least now I can tell the client to accept it the way it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bruno stated that ligatures are not supported for indic language yet. So, if indentation really becomes a necessity then it can be achieveable by the following way, given that I am using older version of itext only for that.

```
Say the text is: "আমার পথ চলা আমার পথে যেনো বেলা শেষে হারায় পথে আমার স্বপ্ন আমার সাথে থাকে স্বপ্নের ভিরে থাকে স্বপ্ন হয়ে রোদ্দুর খুঁজে পাই জীবনের"

And i want to show it in two line as:
আমার পথ চলা আমার পথে যেনো বেলা শেষে হারায় পথে আমার স্বপ্ন
আমার সাথে থাকে স্বপ্নের ভিরে থাকে স্বপ্ন হয়ে রোদ্দুর খুঁজে পাই জীবনের"

then I break it into 4 parts.
txt1="আমার পথ চলা আমার পথে যেনো বেলা শেষে হারায় পথে"
txt2="                                           আমার স্বপ্ন"
txt3="আমার সাথে থাকে স্বপ্নের ভিরে থাকে স্বপ্ন হয়ে রোদ্দুর খুঁজে"
txt4="                                          পাই জীবনের"




    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell();
    c1.setFixedHeight(hght);
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    ITextUtil.setCellBorder(c1, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    ITextUtil.setCellPadding(c1, 0, 7, 0, 0);




    Paragraph phrs1 = new Paragraph(txt1, fnt);
    phrs1.setLeading(12);
    c1.addElement(phrs1);



    Paragraph phrs2 = new Paragraph(txt2, fnt);
    phrs2.setLeading(0);
    c1.addElement(phrs2);


    Paragraph phrs3 = new Paragraph(txt3, fnt);
    phrs3.setLeading(11);
    c1.addElement(phrs3);


    Paragraph phrs4 = new Paragraph(txt4, fnt);
    phrs4.setLeading(0);
    c1.addElement(phrs4);
```

// please note that you may need to change the leading value to adjust, and it is intended for indic language like Bengali, not for English